# Вложенные массивы

Tags: javascript, массивы

Существует несколько двухмерных массивов:

```
array1 [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]],
array2 [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]],
...
arrayN [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]
```

Создаём массив, содержащий все эти массивы:

```
all_arrays [array1, array2, ... arrayN].
```

Как теперь получить значение одного из элементов этого массива?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Указав три индекса - номер массива, первый индекс в массиве, второй индекс в массиве:

```
var value = all_arrays[arrayNumber][i][j];
```

`all_arrays[arrayNumber]` вернет вам обычный двумерный массив (например, `all_arrays[0]` вернет `array1`) , с которым вы вроде бы уже знаете как работать.